# What will a polyurethane resin not adhere to?

Tags: adhesion

For making a mould out of the bicomponent polyurethane resin kit that I have - I am going to need to take out the mould from its form. The mould is what I am actually making from the bicomponent resin.

I have done this once and i know how hard it is to take out the hardened resin out of the form it was poured into.

Is there any material I can apply on the form's walls for a smooth release of the hardened resin ? Maybe some sort of tape or powder ?